# pygame function appears to be being ignored

Tags: python, function, pygame

I'm building a relatively simple programme to test collision detection, it's all working fine at the moment except one thing, I'm trying to make the background colour change randomly, the only issue is that it appears to be completely skipping the function to do this;

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random, math, time, sys
pygame.init()

Surface = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

backgroundr = int(random.random()*255)+1
backgroundg = int(random.random()*255)+1
backgroundb = int(random.random()*255)+1

Circles = []
class Circle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.radius = int(random.random()*50) + 1
        self.x = random.randint(self.radius, 800-self.radius)
        self.y = random.randint(self.radius, 600-self.radius)
        self.speedx = 0.5*(random.random()+1.0)
        self.speedy = 0.5*(random.random()+1.0)
        self.r = int(random.random()*255)+1
        self.g = int(random.random()*255)+1
        self.b = int(random.random()*255)+1
##        self.mass = math.sqrt(self.radius)

for x in range(int(random.random()*30) + 1):
    Circles.append(Circle())

def CircleCollide(C1,C2):
    C1Speed = math.sqrt((C1.speedx**2)+(C1.speedy**2))
    XDiff = -(C1.x-C2.x)
    YDiff = -(C1.y-C2.y)
    if XDiff > 0:
        if YDiff > 0:
            Angle = math.degrees(math.atan(YDiff/XDiff))
            XSpeed = -C1Speed*math.cos(math.radians(Angle))
            YSpeed = -C1Speed*math.sin(math.radians(Angle))
        elif YDiff < 0:
            Angle = math.degrees(math.atan(YDiff/XDiff))
            XSpeed = -C1Speed*math.cos(math.radians(Angle))
            YSpeed = -C1Speed*math.sin(math.radians(Angle))
    elif XDiff < 0:
        if YDiff > 0:
            Angle = 180 + math.degrees(math.atan(YDiff/XDiff))
            XSpeed = -C1Speed*math.cos(math.radians(Angle))
            YSpeed = -C1Speed*math.sin(math.radians(Angle))
        elif YDiff < 0:
            Angle = -180 + math.degrees(math.atan(YDiff/XDiff))
            XSpeed = -C1Speed*math.cos(math.radians(Angle))
            YSpeed = -C1Speed*math.sin(math.radians(Angle))
    elif XDiff == 0:
        if YDiff > 0:
            Angle = -90
        else:
            Angle = 90
        XSpeed = C1Speed*math.cos(math.radians(Angle))
        YSpeed = C1Speed*math.sin(math.radians(Angle))
    elif YDiff == 0:
        if XDiff < 0:
            Angle = 0
        else:
            Angle = 180
        XSpeed = C1Speed*math.cos(math.radians(Angle))
        YSpeed = C1Speed*math.sin(math.radians(Angle))
    C1.speedx = XSpeed
    C1.speedy = YSpeed
    C1.r = int(random.random()*255)+1
    C1.g = int(random.random()*255)+1
    C1.b = int(random.random()*255)+1
    C2.r = int(random.random()*255)+1
    C2.g = int(random.random()*255)+1
    C2.b = int(random.random()*255)+1

def ColourCheck():
    checknumber = int(random.random()*50)+1
    if checknumber == 50:
        backgroundr = int(random.random()*255)+1
        backgroundg = int(random.random()*255)+1
        backgroundb = int(random.random()*255)+1

def Move():
    for Circle in Circles:
        Circle.x += Circle.speedx
        Circle.y += Circle.speedy
def CollisionDetect():
    for Circle in Circles:
        if Circle.x < Circle.radius or Circle.x > 800-Circle.radius:
            Circle.speedx *= -1
            Circle.r = int(random.random()*255)+1
            Circle.g = int(random.random()*255)+1
            Circle.b = int(random.random()*255)+1
        if Circle.y < Circle.radius or Circle.y > 600-Circle.radius:
            Circle.speedy *= -1
            Circle.r = int(random.random()*255)+1
            Circle.g = int(random.random()*255)+1
            Circle.b = int(random.random()*255)+1
    for Circle in Circles:
        for Circle2 in Circles:
            if Circle != Circle2:
                if math.sqrt(  ((Circle.x-Circle2.x)**2)  +  ((Circle.y-Circle2.y)**2)  ) <= (Circle.radius+Circle2.radius):
                    CircleCollide(Circle,Circle2)
def Draw():
    Surface.fill((backgroundr,backgroundg,backgroundb))
    for Circle in Circles:
        pygame.draw.circle(Surface,(Circle.r,Circle.g,Circle.b),(int(Circle.x),int(600-Circle.y)),Circle.radius)
    pygame.display.flip()

def GetInput():
    keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or keystate[K_ESCAPE]:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()

def main():
    while True:
        ColourCheck()
        GetInput()
        Move()
        CollisionDetect()
        Draw()
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

it's the `ColourCheck` function that's being ignored, any ideas why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe backgroundr, backgroundg, and backgroundb are local variables to your ColourCheck() function.

If you're determined to use global variables, try this at the top of your file:

```
global backgroundr;
global backgroundg;
global backgroundb;
backgroundr = int(random.random()*255)+1
backgroundg = int(random.random()*255)+1
backgroundb = int(random.random()*255)+1
```

and this in your function:

```
def ColourCheck():
    global backgroundr;
    global backgroundg;
    global backgroundb;
    checknumber = int(random.random()*50)+1
    if checknumber == 50:
        backgroundr = int(random.random()*255)+1
        backgroundg = int(random.random()*255)+1
        backgroundb = int(random.random()*255)+1
```

Comment: Oh, and it would be wiser to rework things so these simply weren't global variables.  :-)

Comment: awesome thanks :D, now I just need to raise it from 1 in 50 and make it a slightly smoother transition :)

Comment: You don't actually need to declare the three variables global outside of the functions.

Comment: @Dana, you're probably right.  I tend to do it anyway to explicitly remind myself that I'm using the variables as globals.  It also makes me think harder about whether I should really be using globals at all...

Comment: Oh, and the reason I put semicolons is that when I do the globals, I typically do "global myvar; myvar = somevalue" on one line.  So...habit.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

`Move()`, `CollisionDetect()`, and `Draw()` all refer to `Circles`, but don't declare it global.  Try adding a `global Circles` line to the beginning of each function.  Also, I'd recommend changing your variables to lower-case; not only does an initial cap typically indicate a class in Python, but you're actually generating (insignificant) collisions between the `Circle` variable and the `Circle` class.

For example:

```
circles = []

# ...

for x in range(int(random.random()*30) + 1):
    circles.append(Circle())

# ...

def Move():
    global circles

    for circle in circles:
        circle.x += circle.speedx
        circle.y += circle.speedy

# ...
```

**Edit:**

And as Nathan notes, your `backgroundX` variables also need to be declared global in `ColorCheck()` and `Draw()`.

You might consider wrapping all of these functions into a `Game` class (or some such), to avoid working with so many globals.